# Prove that there is an infinite number of rationals between any two reals

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I just stumbled upon this question: [Infinite number of rationals between any two reals.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/199415/infinite-number-of-rationals-between-any-two-reals).

As I' not sure about my idea of a proof, I do not want to post this as an answer there, but rather formulate as a question.

My idea is as follows:

1. $\mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{R}$
2. $\forall a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ with $a>b, \exists q_0 \in \mathbb{Q}$ s.t. $a > q_0 > b$ (which is proven e.g. on [Proofwiki](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Between_Every_Two_Reals_Exists_a_Rational))
3. As $\mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{R}, q_0 \in \mathbb{R}$
4. For $a, q_0$, repeat step 2 to find $q_1 \in \mathbb{Q}$ s.t. $a > q_1 > q_0 > b$
5. Repeat ad infinitum

Thus, there have to be infinitely many rationals between any two reals.

Can you argue like this, or is there anything wrong in my line of reasoning?

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: When you write that down, you ought to use a lot more English words and a lot less symbols. Otherwise it can work. Depending on your context, you may or may not need to flesh out "repeat ad infinitum" more precisely.

Comment: What is the proof of step #2?  All the others are fine.

Comment: @HenningMakholm, what's wrong with using symbols here?

Comment: @bonifaz: It makes your argument more difficult to read than writing things out in prose would be.

Comment: @vadim123, I added a link for a proof of #2. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: In my opinion, all the difficulty is hidden in step 2. All the rest is a formality. So I would definitely write it up as opposed to just relying on a reference.

Answer (score 1):

Since $q_0$ has been found such that $a > q_0 > b$, you can use induction proof:

For all integer $n$, let $P(n)$ be :

**there exist $q_0, \cdots, q_n \in \Bbb Q$ such that $a>q_0> \cdots >q_n >b$.**

Then:

(i)  $P(0)$ is true.

(2)  Let us suppose $P(n)$ true for any $n\in \Bbb N$. Let $q_{n+1} \in \Bbb Q$  such that $ q_n > q_{n+1} > b$ , then $a > q_0 > \cdots > q_n >q_{n+1} > b$  and $P(n+1)$ is true.

Answer (score 0):

I was also thinking along similar lines : Take a rational upper bound A for *a*, and a rational lower bound B for *b* so that $a<A<B<b$, then use the fact that the mean M of two rational numbers is itself rational, since $\mathbb{Q}$ forms a [ring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_%28mathematics%29) with addition (+) and multiplication ($\cdot$) , and then apply it with regards A & M and B & M to find the two new means $M_A$ and $M_B$, and so on and so forth, ad infinitum.

Answer (score 0):

you could use the axiom of archimedes

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on this?

Comment: @amWhy ok so do you know what the axiom states? with that, if we want to find a rational between say a and b, we can find a natural n s.t. a-b>1/n from the axiom, do you see how to proceed from here.....we can say there is a q s.t. q/n is in-between a and b being careful in regards to what is q then we have found a rational.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\alpha, \beta$ be two real numbers such that $\alpha < \beta$. If we use Dedekind cuts for these numbers say $\alpha = \langle A, B \rangle, \beta = \langle C, D \rangle $ then we can see that $\alpha < \beta $ means $A $ is a proper subset of $C$ and hence there are infinitely many rationals lying in $C - A$ and these are all lying between $\alpha $ and $\beta$.

It is bit more difficult to show that there are infinitely many irrationals between $\alpha$ and $\beta$.