# The Denseness of Q

Tags: analysis

I am answering the question:

> Consider $a, b ∈ R$ where $a < b$. Use Denseness of $\mathbb Q$ to show there are infinitely many rationals between $a$ and $b$.

I have chosen to answer this thing using induction.
I know $P_1$ is a true assertion since by the denseness of $\mathbb Q$ there exists a rational, $r_1$ such that $a<r_1<b$. I can then assume $P_n$ is true and that there are $n$ distinct rationals between $a$ and $b$ of the form

$a<r_n<r_{n-1}<r_{n-2}<\cdots<r_2<r_1<b$

This is where I'm stuck but I know I want to use the denseness of $\mathbb Q$ again to say since $a<r_n$, I can find a rational $r_{n+1}$. At the same time, I don't know what it is about $\mathbb Q$ that allows me to say it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Infinite number of rationals between any two reals.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/199415/infinite-number-of-rationals-between-any-two-reals)

Comment: You know that there is a rational $r_{n+1}$ such that $a<r_{n+1}<r_n$.

Answer (score 1):

You're basically there: there's more than any finite number of rationals between $a$ and $b$ because 1. given any finite list of them you can generate more and 2. $a$ and $b$ themselves compose such a finite list; therefore, the number of rationals between $a$ and $b$ is infinite.